# How many arguments were passed?

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming

Using your language of choice, write a function that takes a variable number of arguments and returns the number of arguments it was called with.

Specifics:

- Your language needs to support variadic argument functions: something callable that takes an arbitrary number of arguments and returns a value.
- Parameters must be able to be passed individually. This means that passing an array would only count for one parameter. You can use an "all passed arguments" array if your language supports it; the restriction is on how the function is called.
- Code that calls this function must not be required to pass the number of arguments *in its source*. If a compiler inserts the number of arguments as part of a calling convention, that is allowed.
- The arguments can be of any type you want. You can support only a single type (e.g. only supporting `int` is still valid), arbitrary types (any type of argument is allowed), or any combination of argument types (e.g. first arg is `int`, rest are strings).
- Your function may have a maximum number of arguments (especially since resources are finite), but must support *at least 2* arguments.

Samples:

- `f()` returns `0`
- `f(1)` or `f("a")` returns `1`
- `f([1, 2, 3])` returns `1` as it is passed an array, not 3 arguments
- `f(1, 10)` or `f(1, "a")` returns `2`

As this is code-golf, the winning solution is the one that uses the fewest number of bytes.

Comment: What if the language doesn't allow functions...

Comment: It's not entirely clear (objectively) what is a "function", "return value" or "variadic arguments". For example, would Dodos function be considered as monadic or variadic?

Comment: (I downvoted because the challenge requires unobservable requirements)

Comment: @user202729 If your language doesn't support functions, use another language. It's not a requirement that all languages can compete, part of code golfing is finding the right tool for the job.

Comment: I've already deleted my C and assembly answers, but I figured I'd ask anyway: do answers have to work for *any* number of arguments, or is it OK if there's an upper limit (in this case: 8).

Comment: "the arguments can be of any type; you do not need to support all types or arbitrary types of arguments" -- does that mean we can support a single type of our choosing?

Comment: @Sanchises Some language-specific restrictions are acceptable (being able to read `/dev/urandom` or time or access `argv`). I don't like **this** restriction which make use of the definition of "function" and "variadic" in a language.

Comment: @user202729 I have no problems with the occasional challenge aimed at traditional/high-level languages, just as we have the occasional challenge that is only possible in unusual languages.

Comment: @Sanchises But this requirement is not objective. ...

Comment: Does the number have to be printed, or can it be from stderr?

Comment: Solutions that (I think) under dispute: Haskell (that's not variadic argument, that's multiple curried), Dodos (count argv, while "technically" according to the language spec each function take a **vector of numbers**), Batch (also count argv), Brain-Flak (Brain-Flak doesn't have the concept of "function"), Japt (right in the answer there is "take all of the inputs as an array"), CJam (technically CJam doesn't have "input to function", just a global stack, the calling convention must be made up, according to the answer), APL (see Dennis' comment below the answer), maybe more but I don't know.

Comment: Either the challenge is **unclear** (in defining what's a function and what's variadic) or too many people misunderstand the specification.

Comment: Is "something callable that takes an arbitrary number of arguments and returns a value" specific enough? If a language does not have the concept of a function, then it cannot support variadic functions.

Comment: The problem isn't that it's not specific, the problem is that whether a calling convention counts as taking several arguments individually or not, is for many languages a property of a *description* of the language, or of internal details of how it is implemented, not of the visible behavior of the language itself.

Comment: @user202729 The fact that the Haskell function uses currying [shouldn't be an issue](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/8427#8427).

Comment: @GlennSmith I suggest asking about this question in [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/). This question is not doomed to be closed and people there might say what they think would make the question more clear.

Comment: @user9549915 ... ØrjanJohansen is correct. | Functions can take multiple arguments as an array of arguments too (yes, why not?)...

Comment: didn't know we had to solve the halting problem for language characteristics to have a clear challenge....

Comment: Elaborated on calling conventions (as long as you don't have to pass the length in source it's valid) and maximum number of arguments (>= 2)

Comment: How is "passing an array" different from "passing multiple arguments"? What if our language doesn't have a calling convention (Assembly, CJam) and you have to make up one? You need extra clarification about that.

Comment: If your language doesn't have the concept of arguments / calling convention then it doesn't fit the criteria of supporting arbitrary numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Amstrad CPC Z80 binary call from BASIC, 1 byte, hex encoded

```
C9          : RET
```

(Also 2 and 5 byte versions, see below)

Upon entry to the call, the number of parameters passed will be in the `A` register. The code simply returns immediately. There is no concept of return values in the Z80, just entry and exit states. The value is just "there" accessible in the register since the code changes no input conditions, except for `PC` (the program counter) and `SP` (the stack pointer). However, the value in `A` is not accessible to BASIC and gets overwritten almost immediately.

Examples:

```
CALL &8000, "Hello", "World"
```

`A` = 2

```
CALL &8000, 42
```

`A` = 1

```
CALL &8000
```

`A` = 0

---

By request, here is some code that makes the value accessible in BASIC. I was very surprised to find it could be done in only 5 bytes!:

#### The machine code:

```
12          : LD   (DE), A
13          : INC  DE
AF          : XOR  A
12          : LD   (DE), A
C9          : RET
```

On entry:

- `AF` - the accumulator and flags registers (treated as two 8-bit registers)

  - `A` contains the number of parameters passed, up to the maximum of 32 parameters
  - I'm not sure what's in `F`. It appears to have all flags RESET to `0`, except the two undefined flags which are both `1`. The `Z` flag (zero) is SET to `1` if there were no parameters passed in
- `BC`

  - `B` - 32 minus the number of parameters (`A` + `B` = 32)
  - `C` - `&FF`
- `DE` - The address of the last parameter, or the calling address if no parameters were passed in
- `HL` - The address of the first byte after the tokenised BASIC command currently being executed (either as a program or in immediate command mode)
- `IX` - The stack address of the pointer to the last parameter
- `IY` - `&0000`

The code

1. `L`oa`D`s the address pointed to by `DE` with the value in `A`
2. `INC`rements `DE`
3. `XOR`s `A` (with `A`), giving `&00`
4. `L`oa`D`s the value in `A` to the address pointed to by `DE`
5. `RET`urns

On exit:

- `A` is destroyed (it's always `&00`)
- `DE` is destroyed (it's always one higher than on entry)
- All other registers are preserved

#### The BASIC

Amstrad basic has only three data types, plus simple arrays. By default, all BASIC variables are REAL (signed, 32 bit mantissa, 8 bit exponent), which can be made explicit with `!`. For an INTEGER (signed, 16 bit) use `%` and for a STRING (1 byte string length, up to 255 bytes character data, binary safe) use `$`:

- `x` - REAL (implicit)
- `x!` - REAL (explicit)
- `x%` - INTEGER
- `x$` - STRING

You can also use `DEFINT`, `DEFREAL` and `DEFSTR` with a single letter, or a range of two single letters to specify the default type for all variables starting with that letter, similar to FORTRAN.

- `DEFSTR a`
- `DEFINT x-z`

Now:

- `a` - STRING (implicit)
- `i` - REAL (implicit)
- `x` - INTEGER (implicit)
- `x$` - STRING (explicit)

The easiest type to work with is the integer. The machine code expects the last parameter to passed by address, not value, which is why `@` is prefixed to the variable. The return variable is counted as one of the `CALL`s parameters.

The machine code is called as follows from BASIC (assuming it's loaded at into memory at address `&8000`):

```
CALL &8000, "Hello", "World", 42, @n%
```

`n%` = 4

This will always give the correct result, regardless of the initial value of `n%`.

For a 2-byte version that preserves all input registers:

```
CALL &8003, "Hello", "World", 42, @n%
```

`n%` = 4

This skips the first three bytes, and only gives the correct result if the initial value of `n%` is `0`-`255`. This works because the Z80 is little-endian.

The return parameter must be initialised before being passed, otherwise BASIC will throw an `Improper argument` error. In the below image, I am printing (with the shortcut `?` since I've golfed the demonstration too!) the return values immediately before and after the call to show the value changing. I'm using the value `&FFFF` because that is the binary representation of `-1` for a signed integer. This demonstrates that the 5-byte program correctly writes both bytes, whereas the 2-byte program only writes the low byte and assumes that the high byte is already `&00`.

[image]

Comment: So how does the calling convention you're using return values?  If it doesn't return them in the accumulator, or at all, then your answer is basically inventing a custom calling convention that solves the problem for you (by adding a return register, instead of passing a pointer where you can store `A`, if that's how you might actually do it from BASIC).  Not that there's anything wrong with that, but it might be a more interesting answer to follow an existing calliing convention.

Comment: @PeterCordes Neither Amstrad BASIC nor the Z80 have the concept of scopes. All values are global and are immediately accessible until destroyed. The value of `A` is the same immediately after the `RET` instruction. The lifespan of a value in `A` is very short since it's the accumulator. There's no such thing as `x = CALL &8000, 42`. It would have to be `CALL &8000, x, 42`, and extra Z80 code, but then `x` would be `2`, not `1`.

Comment: I think it's fine if you include the output arg in the count, otherwise there's a 1-byte decrement instruction isn't there?  I'd be interested to see a version that was actually usable from BASIC instead of being trivial.

Comment: @PeterCordes Done! Oh, by the way, I forgot to mention not to call it with no parameters as it will overwrite its own first two instructions with `&00`s - `NOP` no-ops. Another byte can be added to make it safer, but of course without a return parameter it can't set anything.

Answer (score 37):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 11 bytes

```java
a->a.length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jczBaoNAEAbgu0/xk5PCuCRp2qSEFPoAoQePJYdRd81aswnuKJTis9tFkmvtYRj4/5mv5p7Tuvwai4a9x5Gtw08EWCe6NVxovLeVn6IphIk/8loXopQCJ/uQD2FuXd7YAl5YwuqvtsQlUHEmrXXV5wkclOTOTKLBAdHI6RurRrtKzuN@KrNvL/qirp2oW/iVxsVGmThJ/qxXM/2CF3MCrZazJ/9hsCY8ETaEZ8ILYUvYEV4JD3@IhvEX)

Comment: Java beating Javscript is rare enouth to be noticed

Comment: @Therandomguy this requires something like `interface x{void f(Object...a);}` to be defined, and this lambda must be either stored in a variable of that interface type, or be passed to a method expecting that interface type, so I'm not really sure it counts for this challenge (even though usually java lambdas are allowed in codegolf challenges)

Comment: @SamYonnou There is no difference with other lambdas, and as you mentioned, [lambdas are fine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/java-function-literals).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I know that lambdas are allowed, my point was that compared to JavaScript for example, you need a lot more extra code to set it up, even if you are using something like REPL and avoid the need for a main class/method (the need for the interface to be defined is what distinguishes it from JavaScript)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: I know some Java but haven't kept up with it at all.  I was interested to see Sam's comment on what boilerplate is getting swept under the rug in a Java answer that lets it actually be really short.  I agree it should be allowed (even though it does give you something that you don't normally get with Java functions, right, so it's not just boilerplate reduction it's giving you arg-counting built-in).  Besides that, it's still interesting as a reply to "Java beating JS".

Comment: @PeterCordes That's why the "Try it online" link in my answer exists ;-)

Answer (score 32):

## JavaScript, 15 bytes

```
[].push.bind(0)
```

The `Array.prototype.push` function takes any number of arguments, adds them to its array, and returns the size of the array. Therefore, the `push` function used on an empty array returns the number of arguments supplied to `push`.

```
f = [].push.bind(0)

f(10,2,65,7)
> 4

f()
> 0
```

The `.bind(0)` simply gives the `push` function a fixed `this` value so that it can be stored in a variable. In fact, the 7-byte identifier **`[].push`** can be used literally (but not assigned) without `bind`:

```
[].push(10,2,65,7)
> 4

[].push()
> 0
```

Answer (score 20):

## JavaScript (ES6), 16 bytes

```
(...a)=>a.length
```

```js
f=
(...a)=>a.length

console.log(f())
console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(1,2))
console.log(f(1,2,3))
console.log(f(1,2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 19):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>108</strike> <strike>107</strike> <strike>95</strike> 94 bytes

```hs
class T r where z::Int->r
instance T Int where z=id
instance T r=>T(a->r)where z n _=z$n+1
z 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxCoMwFEX3fsUdHBKkoGsg7t3dRMrDBnw0fciLIOTnYzoIrvecc1dK3xBjKUuklDBCcaxBA7JzL9mfgz5Y0k6yhArrcmHPnztRP4yGqm4vAYK3z420ffkRCzw25do3MCajs9gYHYzFNMO5/7UtJw)

This was surprisingly hard to get working, but I had fun trying to find out how to implement something that's trivial in imperative languages.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. `f` is optional if you say `z 0` is the function without the binding, so `main = print $ ((z 0) pi 0 () [] :: Int)` works.

Comment: And by that I mean that the types work when used as an anonymous function so you can indeed remove everything from the last two rows except `z 0`

Comment: Nice, thanks! Turns out I was doing something wrong when I was testing the anonymous function. Tried your example and it worked just fine.

Comment: I guess the `::Int` should be counted in the byte count, since the type of the answer has to be declared sooner or later, like in `main = print $ ((z 0 :: Double -> Integer -> () -> [a] -> (Int->Int->Int) -> IO () -> Int) pi 0 () [] (+) main)`. I also think that this works only during compile time so something like `foldl(\a b->a b) (z 0) $ [1..5])::Int` can't work. Either way, this is great stuff.

Comment: Very nice! Btw. you can remove a superfluous space between `T(a->r)` and `where`.

Comment: `s/imperative/non-curry/`

Comment: @Angs I've been going back and forth on the signature byte count. I feel like it should be included too, but on the other hand, it's +5 bytes per call rather than a constant amount, so assuming it's only used once seems arbitrary. It seemed more consistent to take the signature as a requirement for calling the function and exclude it from the byte count.

Comment: The version in your tio link has an extra space in the second instance, that is not in your answer nor necessary.

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 15 bytes

```python
lambda*a:len(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSvRKic1TyNR839BUWZeiUaahqYmF4xpiMRWSlRCltFRMDRA5WMoMNJRMNZRMNFRMNVRMNNRMNdRsNBRsIRo/A8A)

Comment: Also, Python 2 :)

Comment: It's not at all surprising that this was the first answer. ;)

Answer (score 12):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```sh
<<<$#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGRfn///9p@fn/kxKLAA)

Comment: Though it should probably be wrapped: `f(){ echo $#; }`

Comment: @muru That looks fine as a full program to me.

Comment: Although, I see now that the OP only wants a function...

Comment: @Neil shell scripts act exactly like functions. OP doesn't clear on what a function is, I claim my submission is just a function saved to the disk.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 6 bytes

My first Brain-Flak solution worthy posting, I guess it's the right tool for this job:

```
([]<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fIzrWxk7z////hv91Df8bAAA)

#### Explanation

When executing a Brain-Flak program, initially the left stack contains all arguments. From there it's simply a matter of:

```
(      -- push the following..
 []    --   height of the stack (ie. # of arguments)
   <>  -- ..to the other stack  (toggles to the other stack)
)      --
       -- the right stack now contains the # of arguments which
       -- gets printed implicitly
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 11 bytes

```
Tr[1^{##}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/A/pCjaMK5aWbk2Vu1/QFFmXkl0WrSJjoKpjoKZjoJRbCwXTNBcR0HJRlc3USGvNDcptUgJxi0uASpIV0JSGZyZh8SLjf0PAA)

Suggested by JungHwan Min. Some restrictions (input must be rectangular) but we are not required to handle arbitrary input.

**11 bytes**

```
Length@!##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/DfJzUvvSTDQVFZWe1/QFFmXkl0WrSJjoKpjoKZjoJRbCwXTNBcR0HJRlc3USGvNDcptUgJxi0uASpIV0JSGZyZh8SLjf0PAA)

Another 11 byte solution suggested by Martin Ender. This seems to error when there isn't one input but it still returns the correct value in all cases.

**12 bytes**

```
Length@{##}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/DfJzUvvSTDoVpZuVbtf0BRZl5JdFq0iY6CqY6CmY6CUWwsF0yw2thIx6BWR0HJRlc3USEns7hECcYpLgGqSVdCUhycmYfEi439DwA)

My original solution.

In Mathematica `##` stands for a variadic number of arguments in a function. `{` and `}` wraps them in a list and `Length@` takes the length of this list. `&` at the end turns this into an actual function.

Answer (score 7):

## [C++14 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 34 bytes

As generic variadic lambda function (C++14 required):

```cpp
[](auto...p){return sizeof...(p);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcq7DsIgGAXgnaf4U4dCgiRepkJ9EeOAXAxJC6TAYtNnR@uoQ53OyTmfinH/UKrunFdD0Ua4kPJk5HhBSJYcwEJfrze8dsZYJPNkcpk8JPc0wb4nHAlfKkfOZxil85jMCFLWXadCySAEWEzW@GzG64H//IdNQFvZbqMjbeRdNf/AEz1/s6W@AA)

#### Previous (incorrect) answer: 32 bytes

It was missing the `template<class...T>` and `(p)`

```cpp
int f(T...p){return sizeof...p;}
```

Comment: C++14, C++11 has no generic lambdas.

Comment: You could [add the permissive flag to be able to remove the parenthesis around `p`](https://tio.run/##jcq9DoIwFAXgvU/R4AAkQOLPRNEXMQ71cktuAm3THwcJr24NjjrgdE7O@cDaegBIO9Iwxh47Mj44lNOFMRmD4Yqf0/VWrL1pGlvODkN0mnt6olHrJJYkGOnAJ0m6KGfGfejbFkwMvOu4Kso1PhvqfhQ//34TVLnMt9GhyuQdsn/gsTp9syW9QI1y8KlWFt1E3tMD3w) (and `-w` to turn off the warning).

Comment: @nwp: wouldn't `-fpermissive` cost you the 12 bytes for that option, though?  If it's not standard ISO C++ or GNU C++.

Comment: @PeterCordes It probably does and is intended to avoid having a trivial 0-byte solution for everything by passing the program via command line. I just didn't think about that here because it seems to not be abusive.

Comment: @Quentin fixed -> C++14

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 30 bytes

```r
function(...)length(list(...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP09DT09PMyc1L70kQyMns7gEzNf8n6ahyZWmYQgilBKVwGwdBUMDKAMhZKSjYKyjYKKjYKqjYKajYK6jYKGjYAlW@h8A)

Comment: `function(...)nargs()` is 20 bytes, but using `length(...)` was my initial approach until I googled a `nargs`-like function.

Comment: @Giuseppe hmm, I tried converting the `list(...)` to a logical so `sum()` could be used, but that's tricky :/

Comment: `sum(!!c(...))` also fails on the empty test case

Comment: and `sum(1|c(...))` doesn't cope well with characters

Comment: I've commented to see if taking a single data type is allowed, to try and get `sum(1|c(...))` to work.

Comment: @Giuseppe I doubt it tbh, it'd kinda be against the spirit of the challenge

Comment: But this counts the total number of elements of arrays passed in, not the number of arrays. I don't know if it's possible using combine in place of list here.

Comment: @RoryT hmmmm, you're right. I'm reverting it to `list`

Comment: Also, I think `c` stands for concatenate :)

Comment: Haha, don't try and bait me into that argument ;)

Comment: @RoryT oh actually, R docs say combine. Nevermind :D

Comment: `...length()` [does the same thing](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dots.html) as `length(list(...))`

Comment: @Giuseppe just curious to know why no one ever answered with `nargs` as you suggest? Seems like the natural answer.

Comment: @JayCe eh, JAD has really only been semi-active on PPCG for the last few months, so I am not particularly surprised. You're more than welcome to post it yourself.

Comment: @Giuseppe ty just did that.

Answer (score 7):

## Bash, 12 bytes (thanks to paxdiablo for saving 4)

```
n()(echo $#)
```

Copy and paste at a bash prompt. Then run the n function from the prompt:

```
$ n
0
$ n 46 gr 3443 dad
4
$ n 4fwj23 wrw jdwj 00998 34 eyt q3 vg wq j qw
11
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: can you just say it is a script "./n" and not a function? then it is just:  `echo $#`, 7 bytes. (will be then any shell you use to launch the "./n" script with.  ie, you run bash? then when you:  `./n arg1 ... argn` it will be interpreted by bash.)

Comment: @Olivier Dulac The challenge clearly says a function.

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 9 bytes

```matlab
@()nargin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BQzMvsSg9M@9/moaxjomOeklqcYm6jqUmV5oGCBvqGGr@BwA)

Anonymous function taking any number of arguments (and silently discarding the lot), and outputs the number of arguments through the built-in `nargin`. This does not work in MATLAB, where you would need `varargin` to allow for arbitrary many arguments.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```ruby
->*a{a.size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104rsTpRrzizKrX2f0FpSbFCWnQsF5RhCGcpJSohRHUUDA2QeWiSRjoKxjoKJjoKpjoKZjoK5joKFjoKlmBN/wE)

`*a` is a splat of the arguments, making `a` consume all arguments passed to the Proc. `a.size` obtains its size.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 5 bytes

Thanks [@Joshua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/49934/joshua) for -5 bytes

```perl6
{+@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1yapJD2v1rbIb72v3VBUWZeiUKahqGOgpGOgqXmfwA)

Comment: You could just do `{+@_}`

Comment: @Joshua >_> true, thanks

Comment: You can remove the `sub` in Perl 6 (not in Perl 5, though).

Comment: @nwellnhof Oh, TIL. Perl 6 is so different from Perl 5 >_>

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 9 bytes

```perl
sub{~~@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jo@7@4NKm6rs4hvva/tYqOrVJMnpK1gnJAUWZeiUJ@XqpCQWqRQk5mXipXAViISyVR107DUMdIx1hTB8Ix1THTMdexgHGVEovSS3NT80oMlXTgbCMlTev/AA)

Comment: A quick sitewide search of answers seems to indicate that you can leave out the `sub`

Comment: Protip: TIO let's you copy in PPCG post format (ESC, S, G)

Comment: @ASCII-only Oh nice, thanks! :) As for leaving out the `sub`, I don't think so. It's not a function without it.

Comment: @ASCII-only I'd consider answers without `sub` invalid since the result isn't something you can call or assign to a variable

Answer (score 4):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
f
	dot i f dab
i
	
	dip dot dab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@z5n2P42LMyW/RCFTIU0hJTGJK5OLEyiQWaAAEgQK/P//3/C/0X/L/4ZGxgA)

Uses Dennis' increment function.

### Explanation

```
f                     # definition of f - target function
        dot i f dab   # sum of j(f(all args but first)). recurses until it has 0 args
i                     # definition of i - returns (arg, 1) given 1 arg
                      # arg
        dip dot dab   # 1 (dot dab on list of length 1 returns 0, dip returns |0 - 1|)
```

Alternatively, 32 bytes without recursion in target function (thanks [@Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo))

```
	dot i
i
	dip dot dab dot
	i dab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/58zJb9EIZMrk4szJbNAAcRJSUwC0VycmSDm////Df8b/bf8b2hkDAA)

### Explanation

```
        dot i             # anonymous function: sum of i(args)
                          # here this becomes implicit main
i                         # definition of i - returns a list with all arguments replaced with 1
        dip dot dab dot   # 1 (dab dot returns empty list, dot returns 0, dip returns |0 - 1|
        i dab             # list concatenated with i(all args but first)
```

Comment: Here's another same-length solution [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/58zJb9EIYsri4szJbNAAcRJSUwC0VycWSDm////Df8b/bf8b2hkDAA "Dodos – Try It Online") 
I can't seem to understand why yours works though, could you add an explanation please?

Comment: Hey, you added an explanation to my solution! I wanted one for yours, I know how mine works xD

Comment: @Leo sorry for late reply, idek what I'm doing, just copied Dennis' function, will try to understand asap. I had no idea how dodos works so I figured out what yours did first

Comment: No worries, it was just a funny situation :)

Comment: @Leo ok so does my explanation make sense? (note: I'm on mobile so feel free to edit it to make it better lol)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!

Comment: Is it a typo that `i` defines `j`?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Oops, fixed, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## C++, 72 bytes

```
int f(){return 0;}template<class...P>int f(int,P...p){return f(p...)+1;}
```

Saves bytes by only working with ints.

Comment: You can use `sizeof...`.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 34 bytes

```php
function(...$a){return count($a);}
```

Comment: Nice one! The alternative, for PHP 5.6 and older, is `function(){return func_num_args();}` (35 bytes, posted below).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel This one also [works in PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics).

Comment: You should mention this [works only in PHP 5.6 and newer](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics).

Comment: @axiac You're right, my bad. Was thinking about PHP5.5

Answer (score 4):

## C# .NET, 11 bytes

```csharp
a=>a.Length
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ldJNawIxEAbgu7/ixdMuRK3aT8ReBE96aQ89iIdxd1ZT1kSSse0i/vZt/EKEottLYJJ3ngkkiW8k1nGZ5OQ9xpsakHLOcxKGNoJhtCJHSw87@@REJlNQ3AshLyQ6wRAZ@iip/0rNEZu5LEqgVzsHvqxOMSZtonhnA@@FF142B9Z4m3Pzw2nhkTYcZVG8l69G2hUydapXkVT7rlKsKtdRXXWvHtSjelLP6qUKf5s1/L17hsl0sx@wjau1nB5rc1EciMOCP04CjlYLA@tc2M4LOPbrXHy4ATr/GnvhvZ2VbliCQClshvYtMjp48ZWrksGMkekfTjErkJAXbeaQxe73rtZy7GuQc1RA7LEOk7e1bfkL)

**Explanation:**

In C# .NET `object` is used for multi-type arguments, allowing one to pass integers, strings, characters, etc. as possible inputs. For example:

```csharp
// Can be called like: `F(2)`, `F("test")`, `F('a')`, etc.
void F(object arg){ ... }
```

C# .NET can also have a fixed size of optional arguments. For example:

```csharp
// Can be called like: `F()`, `F(2)`, `F("test")`, `F('a')`, etc.
void F(object arg = null){ ... }
```

And there are also varargs, which is an undefined amount of optional arguments (which is what I've used in this answer). For example:

```csharp
// Can be called like: `F()`, `F(2)`, `F(2, "test", 'a')`, etc.
void F(params object[] args){ ... }
```

Usually lambdas are created like this:

```csharp
System.Func<object[], int> F f = a=>a.Length;
// A call like `f(new object[]{2, "test", 'a'))` will return 3 (size of the input array)
```

But unfortunately `System.Func` doesn't support `params` varargs, so I'll have to create a `delegate` instead:

```csharp
delegate int F(params object[] args);
F f = a=>a.Length;
// A call like `f()` will return 0, and `f(2, "test", 'a')` will return 3
```

Which is my answer for this challenge, and can be found in the linked TIO test code.

---

The only limitation is that inputting an actual `object[]` like `f(new object[]{1,2,3})` will result in 3 instead of 1. `f(new int[]{1,2,3})` will still result in 1, because it interprets the `int[]` as a single `object`. To have the `object[]` parameter be interpret as a single object as well it can be casted to an object like this: `f((object)new object[]{1,2,3})`.

Comment: I have to say, if there were ever an answer that made me support including lambda-related boilerplate in C# answers it would be this one... but it is definitely a valid solution.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Maybe it indeed wasn't very clear what I did without opening the TIO-link, so I've added an explanation.

Comment: Fails when passed a single array as argument.  Ie. f(new object[]{1, 2, 3})

Comment: @Taemyr I tried finding a solution, but unfortunately there is none for C# .NET, except for casting any `object[]` parameters to `object`, like this: `f((object)new object[]{1,2,3});`. There is no way to differentiate between `f(new object[]{1,2,3});` and `f(1,2,3);` as far as I could find.

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##pZI/C8IwEMV3P8XhlOJZrP9FdHG1k4ND6XCNqUZsIk1QpPSz12p1EcGAN9793nvwOG66XOei4icyBsKikspCys6UU2ZAJ0fBbRRHMZC3WJK/FmpvD/MGaq5A@EFDUrNBJ3nTFYCxZCWHi5Y7CEkq5hUtqCeEDBagxBVC5s2fq83NWJH5K62MPgl/m0sr1lIJlvkp81ygwIlqU9vNDYOeI@hu2ccBDnGEY5zgFGeviN/KR1PvmounTemU@EWH/3jVD/AhKltldQc) handles array parameters correctly for a huge penalty of bytes. There might be a more concise structure that can handle it, but it works in my testing.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Hmm, but it fails for `f(1, new object[]{1,2,3})` again though. Not sure if a solution for this behavior can be found.

Comment: Well... I don't know if this was missed or has simply been changed, but reading the Challenge again it appears that both "Supporting only up to a maximum number of inputs" and "Supporting only specific data types" are allowed, so the solution is valid as-is with the simple note "supports data types other than `object[]`", though some other use of those allowances could save characters.

Comment: There may be some benefits to using the `dynamic` type over `object` =>  `delegate int F(params dynamic[] a);`. This saves you from having to type cast the args.

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, 57 bytes

```
macro_rules!f{()=>{0};($($x:expr),+)=>{[$($x),+].len()};}
```

Explanation:

```
macro_rules! f {         // define a macro called f
    () => {0};           // when called without arguments, expand to 0
    ($($x:expr),+) => {  // when called with 1 or more comma seperated arguments
        [                // rust uses [a, b, c] to make an array
            $($x),+      // expand to the arguments seperated with a comma
        ]                
        .len()           // take the length of that.
    };
}
```

Test:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", f!());                // prints 0
    println!("{:?}", f!(4));               // prints 1
    println!("{:?}", f!(5, 2));            // prints 2
    // works with anything, as long as you dont mix things
    println!("{}", f!("", "a", "hello"));  // prints 3
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes

```r
function(...)nargs()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP09DT09PMy@xKL1YQ/N/moahkbEOCJuYWpjrKKUpaXKlaeRkFpcAJXQMTTV1clJLSlKLinUUDK2AykCymv8B)

R has [a function just for that](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/nargs.html).

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 35 bytes

```php
function(){return func_num_args();}
```

[manual entry](http://php.net/func_num_args)

Answer (score 2):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 28 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(&rest a)(length a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJTWtNE8hTUOtKLW4RCFRUyMnNS@9JAPI0vyvUVCUmZesoJGmYKhgpGAJFAEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 3 bytes

```
L,L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx@e/Sk5iblJKooKhHQgZ2SkYc/lzwQW5/P8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
set n=0
for %%a in (%*)do set/an+=1
exit/b%n%
```

No builtin in Batch, so we have to go old-school. Saved 1 byte thanks to @IsmaelMiguel. Outputs via exit code, or save 3 bytes if output via global variable is valid. Example of use in a full program:

```
@echo off
call:c %*
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
exit/b
:c
set n=0
for %%a in (%*)do set/an+=1
exit/b%n%
```

Comment: I believe that this answer is answer goes (somewhat) against the rules. Batch has something somewhat close to functions. You can do something similar to `:a|set r=0&for %%a in (%*)do set/ar+=1` (`|` = windows-style newline). This solution is 38 bytes. To execute it, do `call :a <args>` with a `goto :eof` before the function, being the value available inside the variable `r`. If you want to keep your solution, remove the `/a` on the first `set`, and remove those `@`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Like this? (Note: I didn't include the function name in the byte count, but I did include the function return, which seems reasonable, as there needs to be one somewhere.)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Nice catch with the exit code! I was surprised to see that exitcodes can be larger than 255. An example is the list provided by Symantec: https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-system-error-codes-exit-codes-description

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 11 bytes

```php
<?=$argc-1;
```

Try it online: [1 input](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJbEoPVnX0Pr///@GAA) | [3 inputs](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJbEoPVnX0Pr///@G/43@GwMA)

Comment: I'm not so sure about this one (and it's validity) since it is the count of arguments passed to call PHP.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, see [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2449/58974).

Comment: The question explicitly requires a **function** that **returns** the number, does not display it: *"...write a function that takes a variable number of arguments and returns the number of arguments."*

Comment: Re-quoting the question: "Using your language of choice, write a **function** that takes a variable number of arguments and **returns** the number of arguments it was called with.". Your code doesn't contain functions.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, if that were indeed the case then *many* other solutions would also be invalidated. The norm is to allow solutions to be programmes or functions.

Comment: I believe that all (or, at least, most of) the programming languages that do that do not have a very specific concept of a function. Batch, for example, has something that looks and (somewhat) works like a function. But is just a label pointing to some code. And in that case, I've already left my comment there.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>44</s> <s>30</s> 28 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to  BMO

My first code golf attempt.

```
func(a...int){print(len(a))}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZx5VWmpcMZmloVnMplCUWKaQp2P4HiWok6unpZeaVaFYXFAEpjZzUPI1ETc3a/2kahjpGOsY6BprWXLX/AQ) (outputs to Debug-window instead of STDOUT).

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've edited your post to match the general answer format we use here. Is it possible for you to edit in a link to somewhere where others can test your code, such as [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#)

Comment: added a link to a modified workign example, sadly go only runs main packages

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I noticed you had your TIO-link in your header. So I've put it below it, and fixed the header-link. Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell 3, 25 bytes

```powershell
function a(){$args.Count}
```

Usage:

```powershell
a 1 2 ...
```

Console output for "a 1 2 3"

```powershell
PS: C:\> a 1 2 3
3
```

Pretty self explanatory. Powershell stores all unspecified args in the $args list, so we just grab a count of it. Since the language implicitly writes values to the console, the act of finding the count will print to the console without needing a Write-Host or Write-Output.

Edit: Mistyped; should have been 25 bytes (typed 35).

Comment: You can use `filter` instead of `function`. Or just raw scriptblock:  `.{$args.Count} 1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: Good idea. I chose "function" to fulfill the challenge text: 

`Using your language of choice, write a function that takes a variable number of arguments...`

I guess it depends on how loose the definition of "function" is in this case.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 32-bit (i386) machine code function, 13 bytes

Calling convention: **i386 System V (stack args), with a NULL pointer as a sentinel / terminator for the end-of-arg-list**.  (Clobbers EDI, otherwise complies with SysV).

C (and asm) don't pass type info to variadic functions, so the OP's description of passing integers or arrays with no explicit type info could only be implemented in a convention that passed some kind of struct / class object (or pointers to such), not bare integers on the stack.  So I decided to assume that all the args were non-NULL pointers, and the caller passes a NULL terminator.

**A NULL-terminated pointer list of args is actually used in C for functions like [POSIX `execl(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)**:   `int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ... /* (char  *) NULL */);`

C doesn't allow `int foo(...);` prototypes with no fixed arg, but `int foo();` means the same thing: args unspecified.  (Unlike in C++ where it means `int foo(void)`).  In any case, this is an asm answer.  Coaxing a C compiler to call this function directly is interesting but not required.

`nasm -felf32 -l/dev/stdout arg-count.asm` with some comment lines removed.

```
24                       global argcount_pointer_loop
25                       argcount_pointer_loop:
26                               .entry:
28 00000000 31C0             xor   eax, eax  ; search pattern = NULL
29 00000002 99               cdq             ; counter = 0
30 00000003 89E7             mov   edi, esp
31                       ;    scasd           ; edi+=4; skip retaddr
32                       .scan_args:
33 00000005 42               inc   edx
34 00000006 AF               scasd            ; cmp eax,[edi] / edi+=4
35 00000007 75FC             jne  .scan_args
36                       ;    dec   edx       ; correct for overshoot: don't count terminator
37                       ;    xchg  eax,edx
38 00000009 8D42FE           lea   eax, [edx-2]    ; terminator + ret addr
40 0000000C C3               ret

size = 0D               db $ - .entry
```

The question shows that the function must be able to return 0, and I decided to follow that requirement by not including the terminating NULL pointer in the arg count.  This does cost 1 byte, though.  (For the 12-byte version, remove the LEA and uncomment the `scasd` outside the loop and the `xchg`, but not the `dec edx`.  I used LEA because it costs the same as those other three instructions put together, but is more efficient, so the function is fewer uops.)

**C caller for testing**:

Built with:

```
nasm -felf32 -l /dev/stdout arg-count.asm | cut -b -28,$((28+12))- &&
 gcc -Wall -O3 -g -std=gnu11 -m32 -fcall-used-edi arg-count.c arg-count.o -o ac &&
 ./ac
```

[`-fcall-used-edi`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fcall-used) is required even at -O0 to tell gcc to assume that functions clobber `edi` without saving/restoring it, because I used so many calls in one C statement (the `printf` call) that even `-O0` was using EDI.  It appears to be safe for gcc's `main` to clobber EDI from its own caller (in CRT code), on Linux with glibc, but otherwise it's totally bogus to mix/match code compiled with different `-fcall-used-reg`.  There's no `__attribute__` version of it to let us declare the asm functions with custom calling conventions different from the usual.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int argcount_rep_scas();       // not (...): ISO C requires at least one fixed arg
int argcount_pointer_loop();   // if you declare args at all
int argcount_loopne();

#define TEST(...) printf("count=%d = %d = %d   (scasd/jne) | (rep scas) | (scas/loopne)\n", \
        argcount_pointer_loop(__VA_ARGS__), argcount_rep_scas(__VA_ARGS__), \
        argcount_loopne(__VA_ARGS__))

int main(void) {
    TEST("abc", 0);
    TEST(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0);
    TEST(0);
}
```

Two other versions also came in at 13 bytes: this one based on `loopne` returns a value that's too high by 1.

```
45                       global argcount_loopne
46                       argcount_loopne:
47                           .entry:
49 00000010 31C0             xor   eax, eax  ; search pattern = NULL
50 00000012 31C9             xor   ecx, ecx  ; counter = 0
51 00000014 89E7             mov   edi, esp
52 00000016 AF               scasd           ; edi+=4; skip retaddr
53                       .scan_args:
54 00000017 AF               scasd
55 00000018 E0FD             loopne  .scan_args
56 0000001A 29C8             sub   eax, ecx
58 0000001C C3               ret

size = 0D = 13 bytes               db $ - .entry
```

This version uses rep scasd instead of a loop, but takes the arg count modulo 256.  (Or capped at 256 if the upper bytes of `ecx` are 0 on entry!)

```
63                       ; return int8_t maybe?
64                       global argcount_rep_scas
65                       argcount_rep_scas:
66                               .entry:
67 00000020 31C0             xor   eax, eax
68                           ;    lea   ecx, [eax-1]
69 00000022 B1FF             mov   cl, -1
70 00000024 89E7             mov   edi, esp
71                       ;    scasd              ; skip retaddr
72 00000026 F2AF             repne scasd        ; ecx = -len - 2 (including retaddr)
73 00000028 B0FD             mov   al, -3
74 0000002A 28C8             sub   al, cl       ; eax = -3 +len + 2
75                       ;    dec   eax
76                       ;    dec   eax
77 0000002C C3               ret

size =  0D = 13 bytes         db $ - .entry
```

Amusingly, yet another version based on `inc eax` / `pop edx` / `test edx,edx` / `jnz` came in at 13 bytes.  It's a callee-pops convention, which is never used by C implementations for variadic functions.  (I popped the ret addr into ecx, and jmp ecx instead of ret.  (Or push/ret to not break the return-address predictor stack).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 35 bytes

```js
f=
function(){return arguments.length}

console.log(f(2,5,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cauliflower](https://github.com/broccoli-lang/broccoli), 16 bytes

```
(\((@a))(len@a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04szclMy8kvTy36r2Flq6CS9l8jRkPDIVFTUyMnNQ9E/9fUKCjKzCtR0FBJUzBUMFKwBIoBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8n/0/QeF/kN9/Qy4jLiMLcxNzEwA)

Note: this is a grave and a space

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
Nl
```

I suspect the answer will be similar in many golfing languages, take all of the inputs as an array and return its length.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3y/n/39DLvW0/Hx1LhMjAA)

Comment: Beat me to it. If I haven't done so already: Welcome to Japt! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 26 bytes

Defines function `a` with a `vararg` parameter `x: Any`. Thus, the arguments passed can be anything but `null`.

```
fun a(vararg x:Any)=x.size
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoAgDEDR3VN0BAfdjZh4Bk/QAbERq6lI0MtXnf7w8tc9RWLV@WJAk1FQApRu5Nu60pz0@OqnDYlN7kYRvPspCXEY3PElRTZooK3hG08IOyxePNQtWKv6Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 11 bytes

```clj
#(count %&)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vUVCUmVeioPFfWSM5vxTIUlXT/G@oYKRgrGCiqfkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 11 bytes

```
print(#arg)
```

Try it online: [1 input](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDObEoXfP///@GAA) | [3 inputs](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDObEoXfP///@G/43@GwIA)

Comment: Note that as of Lua 5.1, `arg` only refers to the parameters passed when evaluating the script and does not work when defining a function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 16 bytes

```julia
f(x...)=endof(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TaNCT09P0zY1LyUfyNb871CckV@ukKZhqGOkY6xjomMKhEqJSjqGekaaXP8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
{L%}
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7BL%25%7D&i=2%0A5%0A8%0A3%0A[4+4+6]%0A%22Hello,+world%21%22%0Ainfinity%0A4%0A4%0A%0Athis%0Abetter%0Areturn%0Afour%0A%0AThis%0Ais%0Afive.%0ABelow,+see%0Azero.%0A%0A%0A%0A&a=1&m=1)

Simple. Listifies the entire stack and all input, and returns the resulting length. No thought went into this answer.

Works without the closing brace, but I think that that makes it an incomplete "function" ([block](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/73884)).

Comment: I don't think I realized that it would be a legal program without the closing brace.  Interesting!

Comment: @recursive I was as surprised as you. Though interesting, this sadly seems useless at this point (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem useful for general golfing, which is probably why I didn't make it do anything in particular.  An unterminated block is necessarily at the end of the program, so there's nothing to do but execute it.  You could achieve the same result by "inlining" the contents of the block.  Maybe some day I could make it do something else.  Hm...

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://vim.org), 10 bytes

```
:ec argc()
```

Where "an argument" is a filename for Vim to edit. Hopefully this counts.

Answer (score 1):

**[Avail](http://www.availlang.org/), 32 characters**.

```
Method"f(«_‡,»)"is[t:tuple||t|];
```

Avail's a little different.  Any particular function has fixed arity, so the nearest approximation is a multi-method taking a polyadic argument (shown with spaces)...

```
Method "f(«_‡,»)" is [t : tuple | |t|];
Assert f(10,20,30) = 3;
```

The guillemets say expect multiple arguments (the underscore), separated by commas (the comma after the double-dagger).  The "f", "(", and ")" (and ",") are actual keywords of this method.  The guillemet mechanism is supported by the compiler, which assembles instructions at call sites (like the Assert statement on the second line) to assemble arguments into a tuple, mostly similar to Java.  However, Avail also supports multiple repeated arguments, nested repetitions, strong heterogeneously typed arguments, and a ton more.

In the general spirit of code golf,

```
Method "g(«x‡,»#)" is [w : whole number | w];
Assert g(x,x,x) = 3;
```

The # after the close-guillemet arranges to pass the number of repetitions of the preceding group, rather than the actual tuple.  However, it's pointless to throw away actual arguments, so they're forbidden in such a group.  Only constant tokens are allowed, namely "x" in this case, as reflected in the example assertion.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Since this is code golf, could you include the byte count of the code that is necessary to define `f` (ideally with unnecessary whitespace removed, if any of it *is* unnecessary). A link to an implementation and/or specification of Avail would be great too. :)

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: There's a summary of the *message pattern language* (including the `«p1‡,p2»` format) [in the quick start](http://www.availlang.org/about-avail/learn/quick-start.html#methods-message-pattern-language), and the `|_|` size method is documented [in the stacks here](http://www.availlang.org/about-avail/documentation/stacks/library-documentation/avail/Avail/Foundation/Bootstrap/Primitives/2168035951.html).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
D[$*b$)Rlb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yVaRStJRTMoJ@l/tKGCkYKJglJG5n8A)

Pyth doesn't really support defining variadic functions, but it does allow embedding Python code directly into the source, and Python allows variadic functions. We can get away with just using two bytes of Python code: `*b`, which makes `b` a variadic argument, containing the list of arguments passed in. We redefine the function `[`, which the Pyth parser understands to be a variadic function, and then we simply return the length of `b`.

Note that this can be run on TIO but not the standard Pyth executor at `http://pyth.herokuapp.com/`, due to sandboxing limitations.

Answer (score 1):

## [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), 33 bytes

```
f(p*){
n+=p.MaxIndex()
return n
}
```

The asterisk `*` defines the parameter `p` as a variadic parameter.
`MaxIndex()` returns the highest numeric index which, in this case, is the parameter count.
By starting with nothing and adding the `MaxIndex`, you get a `0` for empty calls.

Here's an example of it in a full program:

```
MsgBox % f()
MsgBox % f(1)
MsgBox % f([1, 2, 3])
MsgBox % f(1, 10)
MsgBox % f(1, "a")

Exit

f(p*){
n+=p.MaxIndex()
return n
}
```

The returns as shown in the message box are (in order) 0,1,1,2,2.

---

## AutoHotkey, 8 bytes

If it is allowable to write an entire program that returns the number of parameters passed to it, the result is much shorter:

```
Send %0%
```

Comment: I don't know this language, but won't something like `return p.MaxIndex()` work?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Unfortunately, that would return an empty value when no parameters are passed instead of the desired value `0`.

Comment: Hm. What about `return 0+p.MaxIndex()`?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Also an empty value. AHK is pretty finnicky about doing math (or any other functions) inside of another function. It's not a very good golfing language.

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 15 bytes

```
main a...{[#a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/PzcxM08hUU9PrzpaOTG29v///4nFKf8TAQ)

`a...` indicates that the program takes in a variable number of arguments

`[  ]` prints the following

- `#a` the length of variable `a`

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 5 bytes (program for Linux, exit status = ret value)

## ia32 (i386) machine code, 4 bytes

This program does `sys_exit(argc)`.

It works for [the x86-64 System V ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented), where the stack on process entry has `argc` followed by `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, ... NULL, `envp[0]`, ..., NULL.  (Or the i386 SysV ABI, where the stack layout is the same, but in 4-byte elements).

`nasm -felf64 -l /dev/stdout arg-count.asm` listing output:

```
 1                                  global _start
 2                                  _start:
 3 00000000 5F                          pop rdi
 4 00000001 B03C                        mov al, 60     ; __NR_exit
 5 00000003 0F05                        syscall
```

Most registers (including `rax`) are zeroed by the kernel on entry to user-space.  To we can set rax=60 with just a `mov al` in a static executable where no dynamic linker code ran first.

Assemble + link into a static executable with
`yasm -felf64 arg-count.asm && ld -o arg-count arg-count.o`

---

```
   32-bit version: nasm -felf32 -l /dev/stdout arg-count.asm 
 1                                  global _start
 2                                  _start:
 3 00000000 5B                          pop ebx
 4 00000001 40                          inc eax       ; __NR_exit = 1
 5 00000002 CD80                        int 0x80

yasm -felf32 arg-count32.asm &&
ld -melf_i386 -o arg-count32 arg-count32.o
```

32-bit `__NR_exit` is 1, so the constant only takes a 1-byte `inc` (the kernel still zeros registers).

---

Note that `argc` includes the first arg passed by the shell which by convention is the name of the executable, but doesn't have to be.  `execve` doesn't care if you exec a process with `argv[0]` being something other than the executable filename.  It's a real arg, and some programs actually use it to figure out how they were invoked (useful for multiple hardlinks to one executable with different behaviours, like busybox can be `ls` or `mv` depending on `argv[0]`)

```
$ ./arg-count ; echo $?     # by convention, program name is passed as a first arg
1
$ ./arg-count a b c d; echo $?
5
$ ./arg-count {a..z} ; echo $?
27
$ ./arg-count $(seq 100); echo $?
101
$ ./empty-args ./arg-count ; echo $?     # runs with argc=0 / argv[0]=NULL
0
```

(`empty-args` is [a wrapper program that calls `execve(argv[1], {NULL}, {NULL})`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290873/224132).  It is possible to "call" the program with an empty argument list, just not from bash directly.)

Note that the `echo $?` is just how you can *see* the exit status printed to the screen.  It's always returned to the shell by this program, whether you print it or not.  The submission is the program's machine code, not the way I run it from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|g
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/Jv3/f1OujNScnHyuaEMdIx1jHZNYLj09Pa5kLnV1AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
|     # Take all new-line separated inputs as a single list
 g    # Take the length of this list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
D[$*N$)lN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yVaRctPRTPH77@SknV0UkpKdnZSdsr/f/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

Variadic functions cannot be defined in pure Pyth, but using the raw Python override `$$`, it's easy. This translates to the Python program:

```
def list(*N):
    print(len(N))
```

Where `[` is the function defined.

Answer (score 1):

### [Spice](https://github.com/Slord6/Spice), 23 bytes

```
;a;return@LEN a return;
```

### Un-golfed explanantion

Spice has no concept of functions - the closest would be a module which are called with the format:

`LOD .\module.spice (^)input result`

Where the result is set to the final value of the variable `return` in the module. The optional `^` character passes the input as the given value rather than flattening the array across all variables in the module. So in this case we can require `^` and:

```
;a;return@     - declare vars
LEN a return;  - Get length of our input, a, and store in result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 2 bytes

```
[]
```

#### Run example

```
$ ./flurry -nin -c "[]" 4 7 2 5 3
5
```

The arguments are pushed to the stack before running the code, and `[]` nilad returns the stack height. Flurry can output via return value (ignoring the stack), so we don't need to do anything about the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
@f:*|!;
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%40f%3A*%7C!%3B&inputs=&header=&footer=1%202%203%203%20%40f%3B%2C%0A3%203%203%203%204%20%40f%3B%2C)

Note the last number before the input called is the no. of arguments.

<sub>shoutout to @lyxal for helping me!</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 17 bytes

```julia
f(x...)=length(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02jQk9PT9M2JzUvvSRDo0Lzv0NxRn65QpqGJheMpZSohOAY6BgiOCVFpak6JjpKFUqa/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

Nothing exciting here. The splat operator (`*`) gathers all of the arguments into an array.

```ruby
->*a{a.size}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhZrdO20EqsT9Yozq1JrIUKrCxTc9DQMdYx0jDUhIgsWQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 31 bytes

```go
func(a...any)int{return len(a)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NCoMwEIX3OcUgFBK0Yl2VanqG7tsuBjUSW6OEWCiSTa_RjRR6jp7D2zT-rD6Y-XjvvT9lM4zQYnbDsoAapSKybhttQk_UxiMP1CD4tzNiu_-JTmUUwzBE9WRSmV4XptMK7oWiyOxija9Jm6Mog56IRoOEA4cocUwh3jn6vvvgdD1fXVhvZ6068CipUplUvt8jcMC2LVROMaiYJSftKgX1NnEO_AgOF-UFa3kAYl7GGLFkXTIMC_8)

Same length as this [Go answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161785/77309) and 2 bytes longer than this [Go answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161774/77309).

Returns a value instead of printing.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 27 bytes

```lisp
(load library
(q(A(length A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jJz8xRSEnM6kosaiSSyNFwU2jUMNRIyc1L70kQ8Hxv4abJpeGm4IhmNQoVEjUhLCAuksUDBWMFIwhAoYKhgZQBkTVfwA)

#### Explanation

`(q (A (expr)))` creates a variadic anonymous function that binds its arglist to `A` and evaluates `(expr)`. Then we just use the `length` function from the library to return the length of `A`.

---

Non-library solution, **33 bytes**:

```lisp
(d F(q(A(i A(a(v(c(q F)(t A)))1)0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy7DYAwEEN7pnDp6ziYIE32OKCJFAEJERLTh08obD1ZTy5hvWI49lq5wDPRMcDReHJmghcWOBFR6SvjZgtimLLlSzr6N9CvH9ek0XNXoBgwtkGh/Q/Nqjc)

```lisp
(d F                                )  ; Define F as
    (q(A                          ))   ; a variadic function:
        (i A                     )     ; If the arglist is not empty:
                       (t A)           ;  Tail of arglist
                (c(q F)     )          ;  Cons the symbol F to the front
              (v             )         ;  Evaluate (calling the function again)
            (a                1)       ;  Add 1 to the result
                                0      ; Otherwise, return 0
```

This approach evaluates some of the arguments multiple times and may generate lots of warning messages; however, I believe it always ultimately returns the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 5 bytes

```
{#__}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@79aOT6@9n9AUWZeSXRadGwsF4xpiMRWSlRCltFRMDRA5WMoMNJRMNZRMNFRMNVRMNNRMNdRsNBRsIRo/A8A)

This is an anonymous lambda. `__` simply represents the arguments passed to it, and `#` calculates the length.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 11 bytes

```clj
#(count %&)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappCm8F9ZIzm/NK9EQVVN878ml0ZBUZ5CtEaapo6CRpqCIYRST1RQT1JQT9aM1fwPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

```
{],}
```

This defines a code block (CJam's [analogous](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) construct to a function) that takes all the stack contents as inputs.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP0fbahgpGAcy6WUmJSsxGXCZfq/Olan9n/dfwA)

#### Explanation

```
{  }    e# Define block
 ]      e# Concatenate all stack into a list
  ,     e# Length
```

Answer (score 0):

## Go, 31 bytes

```
func a(b ...int){print(len(b))}
```

Only works with integers to save space.

[Try it here](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZ9z@tNC9ZIVEjSUFPTy8zr0SzuqAISGnkpOZpJGlq1kLkQSo1NBWquTgTNQx1jHSMdUw0uTghKpVi8pQ04RJYhTEFNblq/wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 27 bytes

```
proc F args {llength $args}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFNIbEovVihOicnNS@9JENBBcSt/V9QWlKsEO0WywVlKBgimEqJSkjiCoYGyDw0SSMFYwUTBVMFMwVzBQsFS7Di/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 23 bytes

In this language, all functions have some special variables.

Luckly, one of them is `argc`, which contains the number of arguments passed to the program or function.

```
{@fna}{@returnargc}{@/}
```

This could be written as `{@fna}{@returnargc}` if it was the last thing in the file.

Alternativelly, running `{@returnargc}` by itself gives you back the number of arguments passed to the program itself.

---

**Ungolfed:**

```
{@fn a}
    {@return argc}
{@/}
```

All whitespace present here is optional.

---

**Example:** count the arguments passed to the function

```
{@fna}{@returnargc}{@/}

{@call a into b 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

{@echo b}
```

---

**How to run:**

1. Get the code from https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate
2. Run the following code:

   ```
   <?php
       include 'SimpleTemplate.php';

       $template = new SimpleTemplate('<code>');

       $template->render();
   ```
3. Done!

(Shamelessly lifted from [Print a word clock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107172/print-a-word-clock/107268#107268) and adapted for this challenge)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 3 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
s£O
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.3/JstxGWT.html?code=c8KjTw%3D%3D&args=YXJnMSBhcmcyIGFyZzMgYXJnNA%3D%3D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), 37 bytes

```
func r(s:Any...)->Int{return s.count}
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/RVFGPT68856)

Comment: As of Swift 5.1, you can remove the word `return` for -7.

Answer (score 0):

## [Visual Basic .NET (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>54</s> 49 bytes

Unfortunately, lambda expressions do not allow ParamArray in VB.net.

```vb
Function F(ParamArray a())
F=a.Count:End Function
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##fZA/C8IwFMRn@ymOTik8i/W/goMUM1kVHJzTNkOlJhATxU8fW8XNdjp4v3ccd498WGgjfaZLV0tknjtV2EorcHYSRty2xogXBIuigG9EnGqn7HqnSvwe/dnlyESlWBQMUq3uupbxxVRW7islGW@df@9JJyCMCZMeHIqwix7kE8f8KgvbBPcHEKaEGWFOWBCWhBUhGTWmtl7T6qPfYfwb)

Comment: [49?](https://tio.run/##fZA/C8IwFMRn@ymOTik8i/W/goMUM1kVHJzTNkOlJhATxU8fW8XNdjp4v3ccd498WGgjfaZLV0tknjtV2EorcHYSRty2xogXBIuigG9EnGqn7HqnSvwe/dnlyESlWBQMUq3uupbxxVRW7islGW@df@9JJyCMCZMeHIqwix7kE8f8KgvbBPcHEKaEGWFOWBCWhBUhGTWmtl7T6qPfYfwb)

Comment: @ASCII-only Oh, I forgot that's how values used to be returned in old VB syntax. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 12 bytes

```
return arg()
```

`arg` without arguments returns the number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 9 bytes

```
Length@*f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n65gq/DfJzUvvSTDQSvtf0BRZl5JdHq0oY6RjrGOiY5pbCwXTKwaKFirU10NFAdSpjpmtbVIsrGx/wE)

[`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) of the [`Length`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html) function, which returns the number of arguments of an expression, and the undefined function `f`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scheme](http://www.scheme-reports.org/), 16 bytes

```
(λ a(length a))
```

Or defining a named function (25 bytes):

```
(define(f . a)(length a))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 17 bytes

An anonymous [yabasic](/questions/tagged/yabasic) function that takes input as discrete arguments and outputs to the console.

```vb
?peek("argument")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/374gNTVbQymxKL00NzWvREnz////bvn5/50Si4C4CgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 27

```
>>,[>,]<[[-]<[<]<+>>[>]<].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpLCsMwDEQP1DQ0bfoJGF3EeKFkEKoEIVT0/K4NXbx5MzDrh9@7fDevlWjINJSU87lFKulElKm0MtY6XW/z/fF8LRc@AA81F@Vwg6hzKKzbAipNCGmH4L5M4QIOSOevzg8)

"arguments" are single characters. output is in ASCII (eg 32 args outputs a space). In order to see output normally, add this thing that I stole from esolang wiki (204 bytes)

```
>>++++++++++<<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>[-]>>>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[>++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<+>+>[-]]<[<[->-<]++++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]<<++++++[-<++++++++>]<.[-]<<[-<+>]<
```

### Explanation

```
>> padding
,[>,] input all
<[ for each
  [-] delete
  <[<]< go back to beginning
  + add one
  >>[>] go to the end
<] go back
<. print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 30 bytes

```lua
function f(...)return#{...}end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/rTQvuSQzP08hTUNPT0@zKLWktChPuRrIrk3NS/lfUJSZV6KRpqHkkZqTk6@ko6BUnl@UkwJiKCppanLB5E2MdBQMjY3NkYQ0Nf8DAA)

Explanation: `...` is used to pass variadic arguments, `{...}` creates a new table and expands the argument list into that table, and `#` is the length operator (for arrays, returns number of elements).

Answer (score 0):

## [C macro (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 61

- 3 bytes saved thanks to @ceilingcat.

I think the only way to do this in [c](/questions/tagged/c) is with a preprocessor macro:

```c
#define f(a...) ({char*s=#a,i=!!*s;for(;*s;)*s++-44||i++;i;})
```

Any symbols and literal integers may be passed.  But passing literal strings containing commas will certainly mess this up.

This can probably be golfed more, but for now its a proof-of-concept.

The arg counter is declared as a char, and is thusly size-limited.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc3LDoIwEAXQfb/iKjFpy0BA8ZWqX@KmKaBNtJqCbpRvx@Lax2xmJid3xiQHY/o@Kqvaugo112maCvCHOWovm22kyW5HI9mo@uK5Cl3IJo6Tong@bRwrqzrRR9aZ062ssGna0l7S444x61qctXV8GLQ/GMJwElKG5S7YgyHU1Qeu@XhS7t2Ywnsh1GfIvwth@hMJs39OKAhzwoKwJKwIa0KeDal3zFftzTtkinX9Cw)

Comment: You can remove the space between `f(a...)` and `({char*s`

Answer (score 0):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 10 bytes

```
(...a)=>#a
```

Funky does this pretty well. I first tried `@#arguments`, however, `arguments` is never actually used by `@` functions, and even if, that turned out larger...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7X0NPTy9R09ZOOfF/QVFmXokGF2eahqEmiDTSUTAGM5ScchIzlMBMTS7N/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 32 bytes

```
int X(params int[] y)=>y.Length;
```

Expression-bodied method with the `params` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2,<s>22 21</s> 15 bytes

```
lambda*a:len(a)
```

EDIT: -1 byte by removing space between "lambda" and "*a"

Edit 2: -6 thanks to @ppperry

Comment: I believe you can save a few bytes by removing the "print"

Answer (score 0):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 1 byte

If I'm understanding it correctly:

```
k
```

### Why does this work?

Assume that the program is a function (the program is technically a function). In this case, you pass arguments into the function in a list like this:

```
[[item1,item2,item3]]
```

Because the main list only supports at most 4 items, we put the arguments in a sub-list of that list (just an optimization, no effect for the source code).

Also, the program technically reads that list of arguments:

```
ak
```

Then it finds the length of a list of its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 2 bytes

```
#:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1K24uJKizZUMFIwjgUxYiG8WABOeQYK)

This is a lame answer, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
L#X
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJMI1giLCJbMSwyLDNdIl0=)

```
L#X
L   # Length
 #X # Of the argument list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 7 bytes

```ruby
:>>&:+@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWy63s7NSstB0gvFUFCm7RhjpGOsaxEIEFCyA0AA)

The `:>>` operator gathers all of the arguments into an array; `:+@` returns its length.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 2 bytes

```
#G
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwcLIpaUlaboWi5TdIYybsQFaCtFcChqVCmEK0bGaYJYhhFJKVIIwog0VjBSMYZIKhgYwFlwFWIGCiYKpgpmCuYKFgqUCUE0sVynEkgULIDQA)

Note that Pip's function-call syntax does not support calling a function with zero arguments, so instead I'm using the `V` operator (call function with given argument list) with an empty list for that test case.

#### Explanation

All functions in Pip are variadic. The list of arguments can be accessed through the local variable `g`.

```lisp
 G  ; Variable preset to {g}, a function that returns its argument list
#   ; Length
    ; The result is a function that returns the length of its arglist
```

Answer (score 0):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s type system, 57 bytes

```typescript
interface F{o:this extends{i:{}[]}?this["i"]["length"]:0}
```

[Try it at the TS playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=58&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIG8D2AuMALYAZ2QgA9IQATQ9YbdAXwG0BdBgfnyKYCJgeWvADYQQAc3wDsABgYBYAFCKwATwAOKAF7IAvMgAUqZADJk6ZHWRMAjABpkAJnsBmewBYWyBgEpemAYoA9IHIoQB67MrqKCq6Bkam5pZMABz2AJz21tKePn4BCsGhyBFRGsikcYYmZhbYVrm+PP4sQSHhkQpAA)

I'm not entirely sure if this is valid, because it's not exactly a "function" in the traditional sense, but it is very similar.

Normal TypeScript type submissions are defined with the `type` keyword, and take input via generic type parameters:

```typescript
type Greet<T extends string> = `Hello, ${T}!`
type Something = Greet<"World">
//   ^? "Hello, World!"
```

These work as functions in most cases, but there are two main cases in which they don't suffice:

- Higher order functions - you can't pass a generic type as an argument to another generic type.
- Variadic arguments - usually this is handled by taking a list as the argument.

There is actually another way to define "functions" in TypeScript, though- one which solves both of these problems, albeit in an *extremely* hacky way:

```typescript
interface Greet {
  o: this extends { i: [infer S extends string] } ? `Hello, ${S}!` : never
}

type Something = (Greet & { i: ["World"] })["o"]
//   ^? "Hello, World!"
```

Within the `interface`, it checks if its own type has a property `i`, and if it does, does something with that value, otherwise returning nothing.

What's very hacky about this is that when you take the intersection type of `Greet` and a record type which has a property `i`, `Greet` takes its own type to have that property.

I couldn't tell you why the TypeScript team decided to make this be the behavior, but it comes in very handy in cases like this.

Since this behavior is rarely used and almost certainly unintentional, there isn't a very common calling convention for these, but the most common one I've seen is taking either a tuple of ordered arguments from a property, or taking a record of named arguments from that property. I've opted to use the former for this submission, as it makes the problem very convenient and short.

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
)L
```

Same concept as many stack based answers; collects everything on the stack into a stack, and gets its length.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/1/T5////8b/Tf@bAwA)

Comment: Submission has to be a function, this looks to be a program taking arguments on the command line?

Comment: @noodleman Full programs haven't been forbidden elsewhere. Either way, prepending `²` to this (giving `²)L`) makes a function with the exact same functionality.

Comment: I think other submissions to this challenge which aren't functions are invalid, per the spec "Using your language of choice, write a function that takes a variable number of arguments and returns the number of arguments it was called with."

Comment: @noodleman To argue against this solution is to invalidate numerous others (And disqualify languages without functions). The only way to confirm it, would be to invoke the challenge author directly. I think it's safe to assume this is a valid submission for now

Answer (score -1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 3 bytes

```python
len
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhaLc1LzIKyb6QVFmXklGkABjehYTU0uJG60oZGxjoKJqZmOgrmFZSyarHpiUrK6joJ6SmqaOnYpsHb1isoqkDzEOpgDAA)

Using the new [community default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25708/114446) that multiple arguments to a function can be taken as a list instead.

Named function which accepts a list of variable length and returns its size.

Comment: IMHO default IO methods don't apply when the challenge explicitly specifies a IO method